# Populate tracking link with tracking number

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

Trying to use this code from details.phtml in popup.html to populate a tracking link for customers.

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($number); ?>
```

My code in popup.html is like this

```
<a href="http://webtrack.dhlglobalmail.com/?trackingnumber=<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($number); ?>" target="_blank"> CLICK HERE</a>
```

Doesn't load the number for some reason but it does on the original phtml.